# IntelliJ "No Scala version specified or detected" at new sbt project

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Iv'e started to learn and use sbt, so far I didn't start project directly from IntelliJ, what I did was pulling some seed project and using IntelliJ with Scala Plugin as IDE.

As long as I kept pulling seed projects and editing them everything was just fine, but when I tried to generate sbt project directly from IntelliJ I followed simple instructions and faced this error

> Error while importing SBT project:
>  Error during sbt execution: No
>   Scala version specified or detected Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0

The auto generated `build.properties` :

```
sbt.version = 1.0.3
```

The auto generated `build.sbt` :

```
name := "MyProject"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
```

And i'm getting "Cannot resolve symbol" on every property at `build.sbt` file..

Things Iv'e tried to solve this problem:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling IntelliJ, IntelliJ Scala Plugin, sbt and scala
2. Adding scala under `Framework Support`
3. Trying to add scala to `Facets` at `Project Structure` (I didn't even have a scala option)
4. Double checking that scala SDK is configured at `Global Libraries` at `Project Structure` with the correct version

My currently environment consist of:
Windows 10
IntelliJ IDEA CE 2017.2.6
IntelliJ Scala Plugin 2017.2.13
Java 8 151
sbt 1.0.3
scala 2.12.4

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to run "Refresh" from SBT tool window? Alos you could try to use newer sbt version (1.0.3).

Comment: The sbt version i have at my `build.properties` is indeed 1.0.3,  
and I installed a new one, still the same error

Comment: Could you try it with clean installation (without importing settings) of 2017.3 EAP: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ ?

Comment: This solved the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this I :

1. Completely uninstalled intellij, with all it's configuration
2. Upgraded to intellij 2017.3 CE